# Biblatex: authordate problems in final bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Using authordate styles, including Chicago and basic authoryear, the final bibliography is printed more or less as such (I use an example from the cms-date-sample file provided with biblatex-chicago):

Rodman, Dennis. 1997. Walk on the Wild Side. With Michael Silver. New York: Delacorte Press.

During the text is cited e.g. as

Rodman 1997, 323-324

I am required by the publisher to print the final bibliography in this form:

Rodman 1997
D. Rodman, Walk on the Wild Side. New York: Delacorte Press, 1997

The final bibliography items should therefore contain:
* the abbreviation as used in the text
* a newline
* the complete data, with the first name in the short form and proceeding the surname.

Is there any style designed for this kind of output?

Comment: Like you have special needs, you should create your own biblatex style which will does exactly what you want. it isn't that hard.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146573/16895.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints to modify the given bibliographic style

To include the citation label at the begin of each  reference (on a line of its own) we first create a new bib macro

```
\newbibmacro{biblabel}{\printnames{labelname}~\printfield{year}\printfield{extradate}\par}
```

to simulate the citation. In style derived from the `standard` biblatex, one would inject the new macro in the `begentry` hook. However, the `chicago.sty` does not use `begentry`. Thus each driver must be modified. A simple ways to do this is to load the `patch` package (i.e., `\usepackage{patch}`) and then use the following commands

```
\xpretobibdriver{article}{\usebibmacro{biblabel}}{}{}
\xpretobibdriver{inproceedings}{\usebibmacro{biblabel}}{}{}
...
```

This must be done for each entry type, a way to do this is

```
\newcommand{\xpatchentrytype}[1]{
  \xpretobibdriver{#1}{\usebibmacro{biblabel}}{}{}
}

\forcsvlist{\xpatchentrytype}{
    article,
    inproceedings,
    book,
    incollection,
    proceedings,
    ...
}
```

For the name all you need is to include  the `firstinits=true` option (i.e., `\usepackage[authordate,firstinits=true]{biblatex-chicago}`) and

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
```