# Citations with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm having a problem with the layout of my reference list. I recently changed from `natbib` to `biblatex`, and I can't figure out how to configure the layout to match the previous style. What I need is the reference in the bibliography to contain the citation in the text, e.g. if I have (Berg et. al., 2012) in the document, I need it appearing first in the reference list, and then the full names of the authors afterwards. Also, I need to make it bold. I want it to look like this:

[image: This is how it should look]

but it looks like this

[image: A short test, trying to figure out biblatex].

I have included the code for my short document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
hyperref=true,
firstinits=true,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear,
dashed=true,
natbib=true,
useprefix=true,
urldate=long,
backend=bibtex
]{biblatex}
%

\addbibresource{litterature}

\begin{document}
Test \parencite{uniprotgfp}.
Test test \parencite{karim}
Test test test \textcite{note}
test\parencite{spi} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Bibliography},nottype=manual]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Web sites},type=manual]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. can you add the relevant bibtex entries too?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you want to prefix each reference in the bibliography with the label (in bold) used to cite it. This can be achieved with the following code

```
\DeclareNameFormat{biblabel}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {#1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{2}
      {\ifnumequal{\value{listtotal}}{2}
        {\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace #1}
        {\addspace\bibstring{et al.}}%
      }
      {}%
    }%
}


\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\textbf{\printnames[biblabel]{labelname}\addcomma\addspace\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}.}\addspace}
```

I suggest to switch the `backend` to `biber`.